# Install/update app from another in iphone

Tags: ios, ios4

I am trying to develop an application which needs to download and install other new new apps or update an existing app in iphone without closing the main app.Is that possible ?.I googled a lot for this and i didnt yet find any solution.Looking far a reply

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. Your app can open links to other apps in the store, but not install or update them.

You have more options using enterprise in-house distribution and MDM, but for app store apps, it's not possible.

For enterprise apps, this link has all the info you need: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009979

Comment: yes actually these are enterprise applications,not available to public ..Is it possible in that case?

Comment: Then it's possible. See this link for information about how to do it: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009979

Comment: Thanks a lot Mortenfast...Do you have any idea about deleting the same enterprise app from the device programatically...I know it is not possible to delete apps from iTunes.Please share you thoughts....

Comment: When you remove a configuration profile from a device, all changes made by the profile will be rolled back, and I would think that includes apps as well, so just delete the profile that installed the app, and the app will be removed.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response...I am trying to install the app on device using the following URL scheme :"itms-services://?action=download-manifest...".In the developer site it is mentioned that the manifest file specified in the URL will be automatically downloaded an installed..But how can we know this location or programatically access this downloaded location to delete this profile....Is that possible?

Comment: I think you need to pair the device with a server using SCEP, and then the server can push commands and profile changes to the device. Apple has a session video from WWDC 2010 that shows how it works.